# DFS and lexicographic path in directed graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, graph-algorithm

- Given directed graph have N(1<=N<=10^5) vertices and M(1<=M<=10^6) edges, no loop-self. Given source vertex s and destination vertex t. Print lexicographical smallest path from s to t (Note: All nodes in this path are distinguish)

> For example: We have N=4 and M=4 and E={{1,4},{4,2},{1,2},{2,3}}, s=1 and t=3. So the answer is 1->2->3.

> This is my attemp: I used DFS-Algorithm to list all path from s to t. And add them into vector<vector>. Then, I sort it and print the first path. But I got TLE.

> Now, I don't know how to optimize this problem, can you help me this stuck

> This is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define maxn (ll)(1e5+5)
#define pb push_back
vector<ll> adj[maxn];
vector<vector<ll>> poi;
vector<ll> really;
ll n,m,i,j,s,d,u,v;
void candy(vector<ll> yui){
   poi.push_back(yui);
   for(i=0;i<poi[0].size();i++) cout<<poi[0][i]+1<<" ";
   exit(0);

}
void aka(ll u, ll d, bool visited[], ll path[], ll &path_index){
   visited[u]=true;
   path[path_index]=u;
   path_index++;
   if(u==d){
      really.clear();
      for(ll i=0;i<path_index;i++)
      really.push_back(path[i]);
      candy(really);
      return ;
   }
   else{
    sort(adj[u].begin(),adj[u].end());
    for(ll i=0;i<adj[u].size();i++)
        if(!visited[adj[u][i]]) aka(adj[u][i],d,visited,path,path_index);
   }
   path_index--;
   visited[u]=false;
}
void solve(ll s, ll d){
   bool visited[maxn];
   ll path[maxn];
   ll path_index = 0;
   for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) visited[i]=false;
   aka(s,d,visited,path,path_index);
}
int main(){
     ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

 cin.tie(NULL);

 cout.tie(NULL);
    cin>>n>>m>>s>>d;
    s--;
    d--;
    while(m--){
        cin>>u>>v;
        u--;v--;
        adj[u].pb(v);
    }
    solve(s,d);
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting all paths from `s` to `t`, you may try the following:
On every DFS call, assuming current node is `n`, get all undiscovered neighbors of `n`, sort them in increasing order and recursively call them starting from the smallest one.
Note that there is no need to reset `visited` status prior to returning because the very first found path from `s` to `t` is the one we need (so we don't need to inspect any other paths)

Two base cases to consider:

1. one of neighbors of `n` is `t`
2. `n` has no undiscovered neighbors

Time complexity is `O(V * VlogV + E)`

Comment: O(V*VlogV+E) with |V|~10^5 may be got TLE

Comment: @knowdont it is still better compared to exponential-time all-path searching, that you have posted

Comment: Yes, it's clearly better than I post. But after I sort all neighbor of all vertex u in V, and immediately break when find one path, but it's still get TLE

Comment: @knowdont well, sorry to hear that, maybe other users will post a better approach

Comment: @knowdont by the way, is the graph a DAG? (directed acyclic). if yes, we may make use of topological sorting

Comment: @mangusta: I don't think you're computing the complexity correctly. In the constraints, |E| << |V|**2; your computation assumes that |E|=O(|V|**2). Every edge is traversed exactly once since you never visit the same vertex twice (although you might push it on the stack many times). So the sum of the length of all the vertices you are sorting is |E| and the maximum size of a single sort is |V|. That means the total amount of sortation time is |E|*log|V|, and the total time of the traverse is O(|V| + |E|*log|V|).

Comment: ...If |E| were not constrained, that would be the same as your formula, but since we know that |E| is much smaller than |V|**2 (at least for those graphs with large |V|), it's a better upper bound.

Comment: I edited my code after I sort neightbor hood of vertex u and it's quite efficiently when got 9/10 test. The last test, I've got TLE

Comment: @rici agree that the sum of all sorted vertices is |E|, but it's a bit unclear why the total amount of sortation time is |E|log|V|. sorting happens on every node, having complexities O(V1logV1), O(V2logV2), etc. where V1 is #of nodes sorted at node1, V2 is the #of nodes sorted at node2 etc. So you propose that O(V1logV1)+O(V2logV2)+... = O(ElogV) but I failed to see the connection

Comment: @mangusta: because every node sorted has a different edge from any other node sorted. They are sorted precisely because they are at the other side of an edge and you never traverse the same edge twice

Comment: In other words, it's evident that the sum of your Vi is at most E and every Vi is <= V. So sum(Vi log Vi) <= sum( Vi log V) = sum(Vi) log V <= E log V.